# Count the number of cells with both specific fill color and cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am using code below but it's not working.

```
Function CountColorValue(CountRange As Range, CountColor As Range, CountVAlue As Range)

  Dim numbers As Long
  Dim Cell As Range

  Set rCell = CountRange

  For Each rCell In CountRange
    If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = Color Then
      If rCell.Value = Value Then
        numbers = numbers + 1
      End If

      GetColorCount = TotalCount

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Humbly suggest you go into the VBE's Tools ► Options and on the Editor property page, put a checkmark beside **Require Variable Declaration**. This will help you avoid misspelling or completely omitting the names of the variables you use.

```
Function CountColorValue(CountRange As Range, CountColor As Range, CountValue As Range)

    Dim iNumbers As Long
    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In CountRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = CountColor.Interior.ColorIndex Then
            If rCell.Value2 = CountValue.Value2 Then
                iNumbers = iNumbers + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell

    CountColorValue = iNumbers

End Function
```

It looked like you were trying to mash together two closely related functions but you cannot use parts of one within the other without correct variable declarations and assignments.

Comment: @Rory - Good catch! Thanks. I'll adjust the function code above.